# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: 7, routes, toolbar

I'm very new to Drupal and I'm receiving the error:

`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

in the following code:

```
$toolbar = $page['toolbar'];
foreach( $toolbar['menu_menu-smart-resources'] as $id => $object ) {
  $toolbar['menu_menu-smart-resources'][$id]['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-role'] = 'foo';      
}
print render($page['toolbar']);
```

Can someone help.

Comment: try print_r() to see the variable is array or object ?

Comment: I have don, it never references stdClass, just array

Comment: if I kill the loop straight after it is declared the is no error, i.e. don't think it is a PHP error as such (i know it is) but maybe something todo with the render() function

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Drupal Answers! Where are you executing this code ? What are you trying to achieve using above code ? Give some depth about this question...

Comment: I want to add a attribute onto the <li>'s of a menu being generated. As I don't know drupal, I was just calling the above code in the page--{pagename}.tpl.php before the render() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to change menu attributes using [Menu Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module . If any customization is needed on top of that then you can follow the below process.

You can able to override theme links using [`theme_menu_link`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) in `template.php`. Follow below step to override.

- Go to your active theme folder might be in *sites/all/theme* or if you are using default theme then themes folder
- Go to the active theme folder
- Look for `template.php`
- Override `theme_menu_link` by copy pasting entire function and replacing theme with your theme name.
- Do your changes inside function wherever necessary!